# Rails - after call ActiveRecord.save successfully, the id still = 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, save

I have an entity which is an ActiveRecord. When I call `entity.save` it returns `true`, and the `entity.new_record?` returns `false`, but the `entity.id` is 0. In the entities table, the new row was still inserted with the correct incremented id. It's very weird.

My rails version was 3.2.8, database is Mysql, and use gem mysql2 (0.3.11). I've struggled with this for a whole day...

Code added: json is a string  from frontend.

```
        o = JSON.parse(CGI.unescape(json))
        if o.has_key?('cls') then
            @r = o['cls']
            cls = o['cls']
            #create
            if o['action'] == 0 then
                entity = Object.const_get(cls).new
                o.each_pair do |k,v|
                    # entity.respond_to?  check method exist
                    if defined? entity[k] then
                        entity[k] = v
                    end
                end

                r = entity.save!
```

and the model (generated by rails g model):

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :iNodeId, :level, :name, :pNodeId, :stationId, :type
end
```

Comment: There's no way we can help if you don't show us the code that does it. Can you add it to your post?

Comment: @Anthony Alberto  I have added the code fragment,  thanks !

Comment: So you're saying that `entity.id` is 0 after the call to `entity.save!`? Can you log it somewhere just after the call to see? Also, do you have any before/after save, updates in the model?

Comment: @Anthony Alberto hi, I just add the model code, it's very simple, I use two ways to check the entity.id: 1. render :inline => entity.id.to_json   2. logger.error entity.id , both of them are 0 ... It's very crazy

Comment: What happens if you call entity.reload

Comment: @dasil003 I tried that and it throw this error :(   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Node with id=0):

Comment: Can you give me the keys in `o` like printing `o.keys`, can you print the output og `k.to_s` inside the `o.each_pair do |k,v|` loop?

Comment: haha ,guys ! I solved the problem by this,:   if defined? entity[k] and k != 'id' then  , it seems like I shouldn't set the id property before save. thanks everyone ! I can have a better sleep tonight ~

Comment: you had an :id key in o?

Comment: Ya, I guess that, thats why asked you to print the keys

Comment: @dasil003 yes ,because I use json to do a map between front and sever, so the properties are equal.

Comment: @Tivon If an answer helped you, select it as the correct answer by ticking the green tick next to it. That will give both you and the answerer a bit of a reputation boost and will indicate to the system that the question is solved. This isn't like a normal internet forum, just changing the title doesn't do anything useful

Comment: @Gareth Done ! Got the workflow ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works by changing

```
if defined? entity[k] then
```

to this

```
if defined? entity[k] and k != 'id' then
```